# Getting 404 error in Rest Api guest-cart. [GET] V1/guest-carts/{cart-id}

Tags: rest, curl, swagger, magento2

I am trying to get my created guest cart through the REST api after i create it with POST /guest-cart/ and use the returned ID.

when i try to get the created cart with

```
/rest/all/V1/guest-carts/{Cart-id}
```

It returns a 404 error

```
{ "message": "No such entity with %fieldName = %fieldValue", "parameters": { "fieldName": "cartId", "fieldValue": null },
```

This is also true when i try it with swagger

```
curl -X GET "http://website.com/default/rest/all/V1/guest-carts/{cart-id}" -H "accept: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer {token}"
```

in both cases I send it with the Authorization and content-type header

I tried making the call in Swagger and Postman

I expect to recieve an empty Guest-cart

Comment: Just to clarify - did you substitute `{Card-id}` with the actual ID value (e.g. `123`)? It's not clear from your examples. Also, can you post the server code of the `/rest/all/V1/guest-carts/{Cart-id}` endpoint?

Comment: @Helen I've tried both and get the same result. I dont manage the Magento code myself :/ but im using the api straight out of the box so there is no custom code in the server code

Comment: @NicoShultz How did you solve this issue,actually i am facing the same but method is post.Can you suggest any fix ??

Comment: @CharulTyagi Ah I did fix it but I did it with trying a lot of diffrent calls and ended up overriding the default magento API and I wouldn't know exacly what I did anymore. 

It had something to do with the cart id I was sending it was the wrong id

Sorry I can't be of more help :/

Comment: @NicoShultz ok thanks for your quick response,i will look forward to fix.

Answer (score 0):

See if you can get a response from the items call using GET - in your case, the response should have no items.

```
/V1/guest-carts/{cartId}/items
```

If this doesnt work, you may have other issues. Cart ID typically expires after 1 hour, so get a new Cart ID for this and future tests. Look into your Magento logs to see if any errors show up with additional info.